# Using Variables with Directories & Filtering

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell, and trying to do something pretty simple (I think). I'm trying to filter down the results of a folder, where I only look at files that start with e02. I tried creating a variable for my folder path, and a variable for the filtered down version. When I get-ChildItem for that filtered down version, it brings back all results. I'm trying to run a loop where I'd rename these files.

File names will be something like e021234, e021235, e021236, I get new files every month with a weird extension I convert to txt. They're always the same couple names, and each file has its own name I'd rename it to. Like e021234 might be Program Alpha.

```
set-location "C:\MYPATH\SAMPLE\"
$dir = "C:\MYPATH\SAMPLE\"
$dirFiltered= get-childItem $dir | where-Object { $_.baseName -like "e02*" } 
get-childItem $dirFiltered |
Foreach-Object {
$name = if ($_.BaseName -eq "e024") {"Four"}
elseif ($_.BaseName -eq "e023") {"Three"}
 get-childitem $dirFiltered | rename-item -newname { $name + ".txt"}   
}
```

Comment: Where's `$sedgwick` coming from? Also, you can simplify things a bit and pipe  `Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter "e02*"` to your ForEach-Object loop. No need to do another `Get-ChildItem` inside it either if you use the $_ automatic variable. Also, it would help if you gave an example of what the final file names should look like in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code. And added some examples of names

Comment: The big problem is that there are 3 calls to `get-childitem` when there should be only one. And the biggest problem is that inside the `ForEach-Object` loop you're using `get-childitem $dirFiltered` when you should use just `$_ | Rename-Item ...`

Comment: The other concern are the `if` conditions inside the loop, what happens if the `BaseName` of the files doesn't exactly match `e024` or `e023` ? `$name` would be null and the file would be renamed to just an extension which will cause errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things I can see that could use some adjustment.

My first thought on this is to reduce the number of places a script has to be edited when changes are needed. I suggest assigning the working directory variable first.

Next, reduce the number of times information is pulled. The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet offers an integrated `-Filter` parameter which is usually more efficient than gathering all the results and filtering afterward. Since we can grab the filtered list right off the bat, the results can be piped directly to the `ForEach` block without going through the variable assignment and secondary filtering.

Then, make sure to initialize `$name` *inside* the loop so it doesn't accidentally cause issues. This is because `$name` remains set to the last value it matched in the if/elseif statements after the script runs.

Next, make use of the fact that `$name` is null so that files that *don't* match your criteria won't be renamed to ".txt".

Finally, perform the rename operation using the `$_` automatic variable representing the current object instead of pulling the information with `Get-ChildItem` again. The curly braces have also been replaced with parenthesis because of the change in the `Rename-Item` syntax.

Updated script:

```
$dir = "C:\MYPATH\SAMPLE\"
Set-Location $dir
Get-ChildItem $dir -Filter "e02*" |
Foreach-Object {
     $name = $null     #initialize name to prevent interference from previous runs
     $name = if ($_.BaseName -eq "e024") {"Four"}
         elseif ($_.BaseName -eq "e023") {"Three"}
     if ($name -ne $null) {
         Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($name + ".txt")
         }
}
```